# How to Display data in JSON if a master query has sub query

Tags: php, arrays, json, oracle

I have a master query, I am getting data from query and showing in JSON form. Now master query has multiple rows in second table which are child rows with foreign key. My master query data showing right JSON with object but I can not merge both with one index

```
{
    "0": [
        {
            "FILE_PATH": "IMG_20190917_11224674.jpg"
        },
        {
            "FILE_PATH": "IMG_20190917_11122730.jpg"
        },
        {
            "FILE_PATH": "20190917_110327.mp4"
        },
        {
            "FILE_PATH": "IMG-20190920-WA0006.jpg"
        },
{
            "FILE_PATH": "20190917_110322150_cf27153e9a2370154223da9c3490e109.mp4"
        }
    ],
    "Result": [
        {
            "INC_ID": "8",
            "INC_NAME": "google map",
            "INC_LOCATION": "Plot 55 K, Block K Model Town, Lahore, Punjab, Pakistan",
            "INC_CATEGORY": "Near Miss",
            "INC_LAT": "31.4842451",
            "INC_LONG": "74.3135311",
            "INC_DATE": "23-SEP-19 05.36.45.000000 PM",
            "UNIT_CODE": "1",
            "INC_REMARKS": "nfjfrjxi",
            "INC_ACTION": "Pending",
            "CREATED_BY": "rashid.hanif@sgroup.pk",
            "UPDATE_BY": null,
            "LOC_ID": "1",
            "INC_DATE_FORM": "23-09-19 05:09:45 PM"
        },
        {
            "INC_ID": "7",
            "INC_NAME": "testing for new versuon ",
            "INC_LOCATION": "Plot 102K, Block K Model Town, Lahore, Punjab, Pakistan",
            "INC_CATEGORY": "Injury",
            "INC_LAT": "0",
            "INC_LONG": "0",
            "INC_DATE": "23-SEP-19 05.34.37.000000 PM",
            "UNIT_CODE": "41",
            "INC_REMARKS": " this",
            "INC_ACTION": "Pending",
            "CREATED_BY": "rashid",
            "UPDATE_BY": null,
            "LOC_ID": "4",
            "INC_DATE_FORM": "23-09-19 05:09:37 PM"
        },



<?php
    include 'connection.php';
    $details = array();
    $details1 = array();
    $UNIT_CODE=$_REQUEST["UNIT_CODE"];
    $query=oci_parse($c,"select a.* , TO_CHAR(INC_DATE,'dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss AM' ) as INC_DATE_FORM from hss_incidents a  where a.UNIT_CODE IN ($UNIT_CODE) ORDER BY INC_DATE DESC
        ");

    $response = oci_execute($query); 

    $B = oci_num_rows($query);
    if($B >= 0){
        while ($row = oci_fetch_array($query, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
            $details[] = $row;
            $ABC=$row['INC_ID'];
            $query1=oci_parse($c,"select FILE_PATH
                from
                hss_incidents  a, hss_location b, hss_files  c
                where a.LOC_ID=B.LOC_ID
                AND a.INC_ID='$ABC'
                ");
            $response1 = oci_execute($query1);
            while ($row1 = oci_fetch_array($query1, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
                $details1[] = $row1;
            } 
        } 

        echo json_encode(array("Result"=>$details,$details1));
    }
    else{

        echo "No Data Found";
    }
?>
```

Expected Result:

```
 "Result": [
        {
            "INC_ID": "8",
            "INC_NAME": "google map",
            "INC_LOCATION": "Plot 55 K, Block K Model Town, Lahore, Punjab, Pakistan",
            "INC_CATEGORY": "Near Miss",
            "INC_LAT": "31.4842451",
            "INC_LONG": "74.3135311",
            "INC_DATE": "23-SEP-19 05.36.45.000000 PM",
            "UNIT_CODE": "1",
            "INC_REMARKS": "nfjfrjxi",
            "INC_ACTION": "Pending",
            "CREATED_BY": "rashid.hanif@sgroup.pk",
            "UPDATE_BY": null,
            "LOC_ID": "1",
            "INC_DATE_FORM": "23-09-19 05:09:45 PM"
        }, "Images"[ {
            "FILE_PATH": "IMG_20190917_11224674.jpg"
        },
        {
            "FILE_PATH": "IMG_20190917_11122730.jpg"
        },
        {
            "FILE_PATH": "20190917_110327.mp4"
        }]
]
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: There is no issue of vulnerability.

Comment: i just want to merge parent and child data with their objects.

Comment: Yes, there is. `$UNIT_CODE` is injected into your SQL. It will break your SQL. You need to use parameter binding.